# BizTalk pipeline issue? EDI not translating to Web Service

Tags: xml, biztalk, edi, biztalk-pipelines

I have tested an EDI file in Visual Studio and the destination schema (Web Service) is populating correctly. However, when I deploy the .dll in production, and I have the send pipeline on my send port set up as Passthrough or XML transmit, the destination schema that is targeted in the map isn't being used. I only get a XML output.

Any ideas on What I'm missing?

Do I need to create a custom pipeline?

Comment: I'm a bit confused, is the target a EDI format or a web service?

Comment: Also what is the source format and what is in your receive pipeline?

Comment: The source format is EDI, and the target/destination format is Web 
Service (which is formatted in XML). My receive pipeline is a passthru.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to create a custom pipeline that contains the EDI Assembler or EDI Dissasembler on for your Receive Location (depending on whether you are sending or receiving a EDI).

However you should see the map producing a XML payload that has the the correct schema namespace.  If you are not getting that, then your map is not executing either.

Reasons for a map not executing.

1. The map in not on the send port.
2. The message being sent to the port does not have a message type on it (usually caused by not having a dissembler on the receive location).
3. The message being sent to the port has a different namespace or root node (message type) than expected as the source message for the map.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want the destination to be the Web Service XML type format. I created the custom pipeline with the EDI assembler and the file wrote out in EDI which isn't what I want. I also tried to put the XML in the Assemble and that didnt work. I also created the pipeline without ANY assembly and that didnt work either. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @CreamAbdulJabbar So what do you have in your receive location pipeline?  Or are you publishing the message from an Orchestration?  Add those details to your question

Comment: Its a passthru. No, I don't have an orchestration for this transaction.

Comment: @CreamAbdulJabbar See point #2 in my answer, you need a EDI dissasembler on your receive location, otherwise the message type will not be set on the message and the map will not execute and your send pipeline will be sending the raw EDI payload.

Answer (score 0):

There was an EDI Receive on my initial Receive Port that caused this issue. I removed it and added my custom pipeline with an EDI Dissembler and got my file that I wanted. Thanks!